# How do I add a button to a table row in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated

I'm putting together a quick and dirty till application for a bar.

When the user clicks a button for the type of drink, a row is added to a table, with a + and - to allow the user to change the quantity.

```
$(".drinkButton").click(function() {

    var destTable = $("#trTable");
    var drinkID = $(this).attr("id");

    switch (drinkID) {
    case 'becks':
        var dName = "Becks";
        var dPrice = "3.00";
        break;
    case 'corona':
        var dName = "Corona";
        var dPrice = "3.00";
        break;
    }

    var newRow = $("<tr><td>" + dName + 
                           "</td><td>" + dPrice + "</td><td>1</td> \
                           <td><input id='Button' type='button' value='-' class='minusButton' /></td> \
                           <td><input id='Button' type='button' value='+' class='plusButton' /></td> \
                           <td>" + dPrice + "</td> \
                  </tr>");

$("#trTable").append(newRow);
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$(".plusButton").click(function() {
    alert('Plus Button Clicked');
});​
```

This works, but the plus and minus buttons that are added don't fire the event.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because event added using `click` or `bind` are executed only once and only for the current `DOM` and not for elements added later, you can either rebind the event whenever the new `.plusButton` is added, or use `on`, which will take care of that for you automatically.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.plusButton', function() {
   // alert etc
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".plusButton").live('click', function() {
    alert('Plus Button Clicked');
});​

//Or

$(".plusButton").on('click', function() {
    alert('Plus Button Clicked');
});​
```

Comment: These two variants behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just after you created your newRow element, you can bind the click event like this:

```
$('.plusButton', newRow).click(function() {
    alert('Plus Button Clicked');
});
```

**Edit:**
You can also use a `on` delegated event handler as shown in NiftyDude's post.
`live` is deprecated, `on` should be used instead (thanks VisioN for pointing out this)

Comment: `live` is deprecated method. Consider using `on` instead.

Comment: Right, forgot this. I am not using it anymore actually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding a dom object(table) after the page is loaded and adding click event on that dom object. It will not work because when $(document).ready() fired that dom object was not present. So you can use any of the two solution given below.

```
$(".plusButton").on('click', function() {
    alert();
}); 

$(".plusButton").live('click', function() {
    alert();
});​
```

​

Comment: Should this go inside the .drinkButton function or after it?